# How to get exposed filter dropdown option selected value in drupal hook

Tags: views, 7

I'm trying to get exposed filter selected value in hook_form_alter().

```
myModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
     if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-view-id-display-id'){
          var_dump($form['exposed_element']['#options']);
     }
}
```

i tried with also

```
$form['exposed_element']['values'],
$form['values']['exposed_element']
$form['exposed_element']
```

But none of them giving me selected option value.

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

For more clarification

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'views_exposed_form':
            switch($form['#id'])
            {
                case 'views-exposed-form-soldproduct-page-1':
                       var_dump($form['exposed_element']['#options']);
                break;
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Where soldproduct is my view name and page-1 is the view display id.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/how-to-get-exposed-filter-dropdown-option-selected-value-in-drupal-hook. Please remove one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, look up the exact filter's name. To do that open your view's builder UI and go to this exposed filter's settings page; look for the "Filter identifier" text field.

After that, you can get the filter's currently selected value in `hook_form_alter()`:

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form'){
        $view = &$form_state['view'];
        if ($view->name == 'your view name' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
            var_dump($view->exposed_input['your filter identifier']);
            // OR
            var_dump($form_state['input']['your filter identifier']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. $form_state['input']['your filter identifier'] works in all situation but $view->exposed_input['your filter identifier'] only works when filter has some applied value means not empty at very first time.